# Add a word to the suggested words list in dictionary

Tags: texstudio, dictionaries

So I write in LaTeX about Tolkien and as you might know words like **Númenor** with some special keys are often used.

So now I would like to write **Numenor** and rightclick this word where I can now choose ***Númenor*** from.

So I already tried to copy/paste Númenor, right-click it and add it to the dictionary. But when I now write Numenor and right-click it I don't get Númenor as suggested word. I cannot really understand.

So what would be the best way for this? And maybe why is my added word not shown in the suggested word list?

Comment: Wouldn't it be as simple and swift to directly type `Númenor` on your keyboard?

Comment: Well I know that I just could that with this word here. But that was not the question anway. And imagine not all words can be written that easy. For instance *Kôr*. I don't how I could write this one on my keyboard. So Just writing *Kor* and right-click would be way easier! =)

Comment: How does that work @ChristianHupfer? Some more infos would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @kwoxer: It's only a LaTeX command, nothing connected to TeXStudio. I don't know how such editors work -- I don't use them

Comment: You could add a macro (in TeXstudio, not in TeX) that replaces `Numenor` with `Númenor` on-the-fly without you needing to interact with it. If you want this not only in your TeX editor but system-wide take a look at [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel is it right that I have to create such a makro for each word? Or can I just define a list (normal written word -> wanted word)? I think an replace at the end or directly copy/pasting the correct is in that case still easier =(

Comment: @kwoxer You can find these macros in the `texstudio.ini` file in `AppData\Roaming\texstudio` (Win 7). The dictionaries can be found in the installation directory of TeXstudio. The "Add to dictionary" function is more a "Ignore this purposely wrong written word if you find it again" (I don't know where these are stored).

Comment: I can as well find the Macros directly in TeXStudio, that was not the point =) I mean if I really have to write more then one macro, it will be way easier to replace all those special words when I finished writing.

Comment: @kwoxer How many words do you have that needs replacing? You could use the Replace function of any editor and maybe again AutoHotkey with a list of words. I don't really know the best way here either …

Comment: Well up to 20-30 I think it would be =/ but I just replace it at the end of all work. Thanks for all your ideas anyway =)

Comment: Are you aware that you can change your keybard layout to use "dead keys"?  Thïs ĩs thê nørmàl wáÿ to tỹpê açceñtéð characters....  Surely way easier than creating ad hoc macros for every Tolkien-based word that contains accents.

Comment: Sure but that it can happen that a wrong accent was used. I would like to be able to reduce this risc by using a list of words. But indeed I know that I could write accents with a usual keyboard. But thank you for the idea.

Comment: Ah, okay then.  A concern about spelling seems surprising since that's a "risc" for even everyday words.  But to each their own.

Answer (score 1):

TeXstudio uses Hunspell as spelling engine. Replacement proposals come from there.

It appears, that Hunspell does not consider Númenor a replacement for Numenor. In contrast, Númeno will have a suggestion for Númenor. This is beyond the control of TeXstudio.

@Qrrbrbirlbel: Your information concerning "Add to dictionary" behaving like "Ignore this word for spellchecking" is somewhat outdated. This was the case in older versions of TXS. By now, user words are added to the Hunspell-Dictionary at runtime using the Hunspell_add() method (and still stored in a .ign file on disk). As far as I know, this is equivalent to having the words in the dictionary in the first place.

**Back to a solution:**
As pointed out in the comments, you really don't want to replace every occurence manually using the context menu. A macro *is* the way to go. For just a few words, one macro per word is fine. If you have more, you could write a generic script, that checks the last word against a list of possible replacements. This [script for autocompletion](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Scripts/#word-completion) may serve as a starting point. It does not exactly do what you want, but the logic is quite similar and should be easily adaptable to your problem.

Comment: Yeah that comes closer to a solution. But let's take the Numenor example again. When I write "N" the next sign would be the special one. So having a completion means that I now have a push a combo to run the macro? Could you maybe give a step-by-step tutorial or just say how I can imagine it to be. That would really help me as I never used macros until now. Thank you.